# Erro ao executar select com alias

Tags: c#, microsoft-access, oledb

Quando executada a query abaixo usando **"AT"** no lugar do **"T"** como alias do join é retornado o seguinte erro: **"IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)."**

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT A.*, " +
                                                 " T.alcadaTipo as alcadaTipoDescricao " +
                                            " FROM tblAlcada A " +
                                           " INNER JOIN tblAlcadaTipo T " +
                                              " ON T.alcadaTipoId = A.alcadaTipo", conn);
```

Alguém saberia me explicar o por que?

Comment: possivelmente o AT é um comando pra query, se quer utilizar como alias coloque entre aspas e faça um teste: `" INNER JOIN tblAlcadaTipo \"AT\" "`

Comment: Mesmo erro.....

Comment: Tentou com aspas simples?

Comment: Sim, simples e duplas com barra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `AT` faz parte das palavras reservadas da engine do access. Você pode tentar colocar ela entre crases: '`AT`'

Lista de palavras reservadas do access: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?CorrelationId=dfea4d70-6495-4477-a24c-3712b25ee85d&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010030643